# Remove lines from pattern to next empty line

Tags: text-processing

I need to remove lines from a pattern to the next empty line.

For example:

```
pets:
- cat
- dog
- fish

fruits:
- apple
- banana
- orange

colors:
- red
- blue
- pink
```

And I want to delete all the lines from "fruit" (pattern) to the next empty line, resulting in a file like this:

```
pets:
- cat
- dog
- fish

colors:
- red
- blue
- pink
```

---

Thank you very much for your answers, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Here is an example of the actual file:

```
2021  29 23 52  12.2358 -23.40477  -68.53253 142.9283 
L01   2021  29 23 52  32.950 
L01   2021  29 23 52  48.440*
L03   2021  29 23 52  32.730 
L03   2021  29 23 52  48.030 

2021  30  0 44  57.**** -23.****  -68.**** 149.****                                        
L02   2021  30  0 45  19.109
L02   2021  30  0 45  37.419
L04   2021  30  0 45  19.899
L04   2021  30  0 45  38.879

2021  30  1  6  32.7126 -23.45682  -68.65472 100.2616 
L01   2021  30  1  6  48.010
L01   2021  30  1  6  59.480*
L02   2021  30  1  6  47.970
L02   2021  30  1  6  59.380
```

*WHAT I NEED*: I need to delete the data set where **** appears in the header, in this case to delete:

```
2021  30  0 44  57.**** -23.****  -68.**** 149.****                                        
L02   2021  30  0 45  19.109
L02   2021  30  0 45  37.419
L04   2021  30  0 45  19.899
L04   2021  30  0 45  38.879
```

obtaining as final file this data:

```
2021  29 23 52  12.2358 -23.40477  -68.53253 142.9283 
L01   2021  29 23 52  32.950 
L01   2021  29 23 52  48.440*
L03   2021  29 23 52  32.730 
L03   2021  29 23 52  48.030 

2021  30  1  6  32.7126 -23.45682  -68.65472 100.2616 
L01   2021  30  1  6  48.010
L01   2021  30  1  6  59.480*
L02   2021  30  1  6  47.970
L02   2021  30  1  6  59.380
```

*WHAT I did*:

```
sed '/\*\*\*/,/^$/d' filename.data
```

and

```
awk '/\*\*\*/,/^$/{next}1' filename.data
```

But delete everything after the pattern, keeping only the first group, with this result:

```
2021  29 23 52  12.2358 -23.40477  -68.53253 142.9283 
L01   2021  29 23 52  32.950 
L01   2021  29 23 52  48.440*
L03   2021  29 23 52  32.730 
L03   2021  29 23 52  48.030
```

and nothing else, all the rest is deleted.

I hope my question is understood.

And about CSH and BASH, I know they are shells, I meant I have the command I use I have to be able to use it in CSH.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had shown the real data from the start, and not after you had received 4 answers, all assuming you had data that looked differently.

Comment: From your description of pbm, it iseems the 2nd regex never evaluated to true. One possible reason could be non Unix line endings. Check if there are CR line en

Comment: You adapted the `sed` script correctly to your needs. If it deletes everything to the end of the file, than the »empty line« is probably not really empty. Could it be there are some spaces or tabs or windows line endings?

Answer (score 7):

`csh` and `bash` are shells, not intended for text processing, but you can call a text processing utility like `sed` from those shells. With `sed`, you can delete a range of lines between two patterns like this:

```
sed '/^fruits:/,/^$/d' yourfile
```

Explanation: The pattern `^fruits:` matches lines starting with `fruits:`, the pattern `^$` matches an empty line (`^` is start of line, `$` is end of line). Separating those patterns with `,` means, the following command will be applied to all lines in that range, and that command is `d` (delete).

Answer (score 3):

If this is a YAML file and you want to delete the `fruits` section, it's best to use a YAML-aware tool for it, such as `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/:

```
$ yq -y 'del(.fruits)' file
pets:
  - cat
  - dog
  - fish
colors:
  - red
  - blue
  - pink
```

Comment: is there a way to keep single empty line between sections?

Comment: @αғsнιη If it really is a YAML document, the blank lines would not be essential. Any parser would most likely discard them.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^fruits/,/^$/{next}1' infile
```

print by default but skip everything start from the matched pattern *`fruits`* at the beginning of a line until up to the first empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{arr[NR]=$0}/fruits/,/^$/ { if (/fruits/) line1=NR; if (/^$/) line2=NR}END{for(j=line1;j<=line2;j++) delete arr[j] ; for (i in arr) print arr[i]}' file

 pets:
 - cat
 - dog
 - fish

 colors:
 - red
 - blue
 - pink
```

In main block, first an array `arr` is created that is indexed on record
numbers.

Then with this expression `if (/fruit/) line1=NR;`, line matching first
pattern is found. Similarly next empty line is found. Now elements of
array `arr` between these records and elements of `arr` containing these records are deleted.

In `END` block, a for loop prints the remaining lines.